# How do you use npm as a source for types in Deno's config?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, deno

I have a deno app with the following config:

```
{
  "imports": {
    "express": "npm:express@4.18.2",
    "lodash": "https://esm.sh/lodash@4.17.21"
  },
  "tasks": {
    "dev": "deno run --allow-net --allow-read --allow-env --watch main.ts"
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["npm:@types/express@4.17.15"]
  }
}
```

And I am pointing at it with my `.vscode/settings.json` as follows:

`"deno.config": "./deno/deno.jsonc"`

However, vscode is unable to resolve the types.

It works when using this syntax inside the file:

`// @deno-types="npm:@types/express@4.17.15"`

How do you properly translate these in-file type imports into the config file?